# Cast Dialog not showing artist value for MEDIA_TYPE_MUSIC_TRACK type

Tags: android, chromecast

I'm building an app that casts music to screens through Chromecast. The new V3 SDK introduced controls to the [`CastDialog`](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/design_checklist/cast-dialog#sender-cast-menu-casting), and to follow Google's guidelines I should set the title and artist names to the dialog.

Apparently I'm doing something wrong, but I can't make it work when running the following code:

```
MediaMetadata mediaMetadata = new MediaMetadata(MediaMetadata.MEDIA_TYPE_MUSIC_TRACK);
mediaMetadata.putString(MediaMetadata.KEY_TITLE, "Track title");
mediaMetadata.putString(MediaMetadata.KEY_ARTIST, "Artist");

...

new MediaInfo.Builder(...)
            .setContentType("audio/mp3")
            .setStreamType(MediaInfo.STREAM_TYPE_BUFFERED)
            .setMetadata(mediaMetadata)
            .build();
```

Weirdly enough, it does work when I change the `MediaMetadata` type to `MEDIA_TYPE_MOVIE` and the `MediaMetadata.KEY_ARTIST` key to `MediaMetadata.KEY_SUBTITLE` (which most samples out there use), but I'm afraid using that as a hack might cause potential problems in the future.

What am I doing wrong in this case? Is there any reason the artist name is not being correctly set in the `CastDialog`?

Comment: Having the same issue. Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Nope, I guess the functionality simply doesn't work.